# Hive HQL Query takes longer time to execute, any optimization on this query will be helpful

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive

**Overview**

I have a **clouddb.transaction** table which is 80 TB in size.

This will be joined with **input_parameters** table which at any time will have 1 to 10 records.

When I ran the below hive query it took 23 mins to execute in Spark and created 137843 Tasks.

Request the forum to advise if there is any better optimization I can do on this query.

```
Select DISTINCT
b.batch_id,
b.sid,
b.cust_id,
b.acc_no,
a.debit_11,
a.credit_13,
a.debit_15,
a.amount,
a.conversion_amount,
a.curr_cd,
a.apv_deny_cd,
a.approval,
a.sed10,
a.sed_pkey,
a.time_of_day_in,
a.auth_date,
a.atm_terminal_id,
a.atm_location_addr,
a.atm_street_addr,
a.atm_city_nm,
a.atm_state_cd,
a.atm_country_cd,
a.atm_zip_cd,
a.atm_country,
a.trx_1,
a.trx_2,
a.trx_3,
a.trx_4,
a.trx_5,
a.trx_6,
a.trx_7,
a.trx8
FROM
(Select cas.debit_11 as debit_11,
cas.credit_13 as credit_13,
cas.debit_15 as debit_15,
cas.amount as amount,
cas.conversion_amount as conversion_amount,
cas.curr_cd as curr_cd,
CASE WHEN cas.appr_deny_cd in ('0','1','6') THEN 'Approved' WHEN cas.appr_deny_cd = '2' THEN 'System Denied' WHEN cas.appr_deny_cd = '3' THEN 'Authorizer Denied' WHEN cas.appr_deny_cd = '4' THEN 'System Pending' WHEN cas.appr_deny_cd = '5' THEN 'Auth Pending' WHEN cas.appr_deny_cd = '7' THEN 'Denied' WHEN cas.appr_deny_cd = '8' THEN 'Pending' WHEN cas.appr_deny_cd = '9' THEN 'Timeout - Reject' ELSE cas.appr_deny_cd END as approval_deny_cd,
CASE WHEN appr_deny_cd in ('0','1','6') then 'approved' ELSE 'declined' END as approval,
cas.sed10 as sed10,
cas.sed_pkey as sed_pkey,
cas.time_of_day_in as time_of_day_in,
cas.trans_dt as Auth_date,
cas.atm_terminal_id,
cas.atm_location_addr,
cas.atm_street_addr,
cas.atm_city_nm,
cas.atm_state_cd,
cas.atm_country_cd,
cas.atm_zip_cd,
cas.atm_country,
cas.trx_1,
cas.trx_2,
cas.trx_3,
cas.trx_4,
cas.trx_5,
cas.trx_6,
cas.trx_7,
cas.trx_8 from clouddb.transaction cas
where cas.trans_dt between DATE_SUB(current_date(),180) and current_date()) a
JOIN 
(select in_tb.batch_id,in_tb.sid,in_tb.cust_id,in_tb.acc_no,in_tb.credit_13,in_tb.from_date_filter,in_tb.to_date_filter from input_parameters in_tb) b
ON b.credit_13 = a.credit_13 where a.auth_date between NVL(b.from_date_filter,DATE_SUB(current_date(), 730)) and NVL(b.to_date_filter,current_date());
```

Comment: your query looks optimized. try to reduce number of columns if you can. Use `CTE` if that makes it fast.

Comment: @Koushik - Thank You for the suggestion. I need all the columns in my result set for reporting

Comment: oh pls remove distinct at all costs. Identify unique keys and join on them. if you dont have unique use row_number() over partition by to remove duplicates and then join. This will definitely improve pref

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to improve performance while writing spark/hive queries.

1. Use partitions
2. In your above example, as you've mentioned input_parameters table as only 1-10 records at any time. Try to broadcast this table across all executors. i.e., enable broadcast join if not already enabled.
3. Avoid data skewing, use salting if needed. Also try to parallelise the data.
4. Try to use vectorization.
5. Enable dynamic partitioning in hive

```
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=true;
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled=true;
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=true;
```

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
```

6. Visit this link for more information
   https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html

Comment: Thank You @Tejeshwar. Will check if the mentioned steps have been implemented in my scenario